# convert datetime format to 'a time ago' in django

Tags: python, django

I want to change datetime format to 'a time ago'. I know there are several ways to do that.

My first question is what is the best way? (using script in html template, do that in views.py or etc)

I write the code in views.py, but datetime doesn't show in template.

This is the code for convert datetime:

```
date = float(models.Catalogue.objects.get())
d_str = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date / 1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
d_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(d_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_ago = timeago.format(d_datetime, now, 'fa_IR')
```

views.py:

```
class crawler(generic.ListView):
    paginate_by = 12
    model = models.Catalogue
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        for cat in models.Catalogue.objects.all():
            if models.Catalogue.source == 'kilid':
                date = float(models.Catalogue.objects.get())
                d_str = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date / 1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                d_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(d_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                time_ago = timeago.format(d_datetime, now, 'fa_IR')
                context['time_ago'] = time_ago
        return context
```

index.html:

```
<div class="card-footer" dir="rtl" style="text-align:right">
     <small id="datetime">{{ time_ago }}</small>
</div>
```

And then, if I want to write it in a script, how can I do that?

Comment: If `models.Catalogue.source == 'kilid'` is false for every `cat` object, `time_ago` is never calculated and set.

Comment: By the way, why not use `models.Catalogue.filter(source__exact='kilid')`?

Comment: @00 For now, all source records are 'kilid' ,,, but there are 8 different sources with different time formats that I have to convert with different code

Comment: With the development server, it may be worth printing out `context` just before returning, to see what it contains.

Comment: It seems rather vague what `models.Catalogue.objects.get()` does: `get()` doesn't have any arguments, so how does it get just one object?

Comment: @00 How can I get just one object?

Comment: @00 I have write ```print('log log log log ', time_ago)``` after context, but nothing printed in the console

Comment: `models.Catalogue.source == 'kilid'` doesn't make sense either; as a result, it's probably always false. Don't you mean `cat.source == 'kilid'` (I don't know your model).

Comment: I think you may want to read up some more on the Django documentation, and how to perform queries.

Answer (score 3):

I explain you quickly how to implement it, first you must install that package in your apps, for that you must add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, leaving you something like this:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ....
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]
```

Now in your templates you indicate that you will make use of that APP by adding this at the beginning:
`{% load humanize %}`

Now when you display a date you do it placing a pipe after the variable and indicating one of the options of this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/humanize/, looking something like this:
`{{ notification.date|naturaltime }}}`

At the end of your template it should look like:

```py
% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load humanize %}

{% block content %}
  <ul>
    {% for notification in notifications %}
      <li>
        {{ notification }}
        <small>{{ notification.date|naturaltime }}</small>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks ... but the original time format in my db is milis since epoch ... and I want to convert it